# subsequent call to fgets function in c not getting desired results

Tags: c, arrays, string, fgets

I was just trying a random code and found a strange issue. Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
char name[6],name2[6];
fgets(name,100,stdin);
fgets(name2,100,stdin);
printf("%s\n",name);
printf("%s\n",name2);
return 0;
}
```

This code is only printing what I have provided as input in name2 array and it's not printing the name array

---

For example: on inputs

```
abcdef
zyxwvu
```

the code is only printing the below string

```
zyxwvu
```

---

Another issue: if I give second string that is larger than the size. For example:

```
abcdef
zyxwvug      // name2 is defined to be 6 characters and I have given 7 here
```

then its printing :

```
g
zyxwvug
```

---

Please help me in understanding whats going on. I am using Gcc compiler on code: blocks IDE :)

Comment: `char name[6],name2[6];
fgets(name,100,stdin);
fgets(name2,100,stdin)` --> `char name[8],name2[8];
fgets(name,8,stdin);
fgets(name2,8,stdin)`

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Improve your code to get no warnings. Use the debugger `gdb` and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: You're writing out of bounds of the arrays, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Read much more about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: If you want to enter six characters, the array has to be at least `[7]`, because you need room for the null character at the end.

Comment: String in c is null terminated in that it needs extra one character. Check how many character your entering?

Comment: And why are you using `100` in the calls to `fgets()` when the arrays are only 6 characters?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes , after changing the array size to 8 the code is giving desired output. thanks !! But why is it not working with size 6 ? can you please explain this a bit more.

Comment: if you enter `abcdef`, Store six character + one newline + null-character. So You need an array of at least 8 sizes.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks i get this , but what about my second issue that i posted. ? Any explanation about that

Comment: _second issue_ ? That is undefined behavior as already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments, your problem comes from the usage of `fgets`.

**fgets**

If we read [fgets manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

> fgets() reads in at most **one less** than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (`\0`) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

What does that mean?

When you write `fgets(name, 100, stdin);`, that suppose:

- data will read from `stdin`,
- data will be stored in `name`,
- at most 99 characters will be read from `stdin` and stored into `name`,
- a `\0` character will be added to `name`.

**strings**

What does that mean, we try to read 100 characters, we only get 99?

That is due to string storing in C: a string is a sequel of characters, terminated by a `\0`.

Using this fact, functions and people know how long is a string is.

Think of `strlen` or `strcpy` functions.

For instance:

```
/* this string is valid: we explictily terminate it */
char valid_string[5] = {'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', '\n'};

/* this string is not: we do not know what is after the 'd' in memory
   the next '\0' can be far away... */
char valid_string[3] = {'b', 'a', 'd'};
```

**your problem**

So your problem is the following:

- you reserve two array of 6 characters counting the `\0`, you will only be able to store 5 char in these strings
- you tell `fgets` that it is okay to use 100 characters in your string.

When running the program, if you give:

- 4 char or less string (ex: "abcd"): that will works, `fgets` will write `abcd\n\0` in `name`
- 5 char or more string: you will have an undefined behavior: the extra character will be stored after the string, as you noticed it: when you give `zyxwvug` for the second string, the first is getting over written...

**How to fix it**

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define STRING_SIZE 6
#define STRING_SIZE_INCLUDING_FINAL_0 (STRING_SIZE+1)

int main(void) {
    /* defines array to store what we want (6 char string here) */
    char name[STRING_SIZE_INCLUDING_FINAL_0];
    char name2[STRING_SIZE_INCLUDING_FINAL_0];

    /* use fgets we right way:
       fgets is told what is the size of my arrays.
       Warning, this sizeof operation won't work with pointers... */
    fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
    fgets(name2, sizeof name2, stdin);

    /* display the result */
    printf("'%s'\n",name);
    printf("'%s'\n",name2);
    return 0;
}
```